# Spring Boot define sequence of bean loading

Tags: spring-boot

I have two packages:

```
com.example.commons
com.example.api
```

The *RestController* components defined in *com.example.api* depends on the repositories which are defined in *com.example.commons*.

The *commons-module* is a separate module which contains the commons package and the *api-module* is a separate module which contains the package api.

Now when the api starts execution, spring doesn't load the repositories defined in *commons* module before and hence the execution fails because *api* package contained under *api-module* depends on those beans in commons.

Here is how the API module is starting execution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.commons", "com.example.api"})
public class ApiMain {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that all the beans in *com.example.commons* are loaded first?

Comment: When you say module, is it a different maven module ?

Comment: @Sakalya yes, it is a different maven module

Answer (score 0):

You can you use @DependsOn annotation.
This will make sure, whatever dependency you are injecting its beans is created.

Comment: I thought too. But there are several classes and this will make the code ugly. Is there a way to configure \@DependsOn or \@Conditional globally?